# javascript copy to clipboard function doesn't work

Tags: javascript

I use this code to copy the text from ‘div1’ id to clipboard. It works but when i select other text in the page and tap the copy the text button it copies the selected text and not the div1 id text. I need every time to copy the div1 id text. What is wrong?

```
   <?php  
 echo <div id="div2">   

        '<button class="btn-light"  id="button1" onclick="CopyToClipboard(\'div1\')" 
        data-toggle="tooltip" title="Copy">Copy the text</button>

        <div id="div1" >  ';
        echo "copy it";

        echo '</div>';

echo '</div>'; 
   ?> 

      <script type='text/javascript'>

                                    function CopyToClipboard(containerid) {
        if (document.selection) {
            var range = document.body.createTextRange();
            range.moveToElementText(document.getElementById(containerid));
            range.select().createTextRange();
            document.execCommand("copy");


        } else if (window.getSelection) {
            var range = document.createRange();
             range.selectNode(document.getElementById(containerid));
             window.getSelection().addRange(range);
             document.execCommand("copy");
             alert("Copied")

        </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work.  I am using FireFox, although it is going to deselect the other selection, select your div, and then copy it to the clipboard.  I suppose there is a way to execute the copy and then return things to the state before execution of your function.

```js
function CopyToClipboard(containerid) {
        if (document.selection) {
            var range = document.body.createTextRange();
            range.moveToElementText(document.getElementById(containerid));
            range.select();
        } else if (window.getSelection) {
            var range = document.createRange();
            range.selectNode(document.getElementById(containerid));
            window.getSelection().empty();
            window.getSelection().addRange(range);
        }
        document.execCommand("Copy");
}
```

```html
<div id="div2">   

   <button class="btn-light"  id="button1" onclick="CopyToClipboard('div1')" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Copy">Copy the text</button>

     <div id="div1" >copy it</div>
     <div id="div3">Other Text</div>
     
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope I interpreted your question correctly.  You can modify that to keep the original selection after you copy you div to the clipboard.  Fast enough that the user probably would even notice.

```js
var savedSelection;
function CopyToClipboard(containerid) {

   if (window.getSelection) {
        var sel = window.getSelection();
        if (sel.getRangeAt && sel.rangeCount) {
            savedSelection = sel.getRangeAt(0);
        }
    } else if (document.selection && document.selection.createRange) {
        savedSelection =  document.selection.createRange();
    }
    
    if (document.selection) {
        var range = document.body.createTextRange();
        range.moveToElementText(document.getElementById(containerid));
        range.select();
        
    } else if (window.getSelection) {
        var range = document.createRange();
        range.selectNode(document.getElementById(containerid));
        window.getSelection().empty();
        window.getSelection().addRange(range);
    }
    
    document.execCommand("Copy");
    
    if (savedSelection) {
    
    if (window.getSelection) {
        var sel = window.getSelection();
        sel.removeAllRanges();
        sel.addRange(savedSelection);
        
    } else if (document.selection && savedSelection.select) {
        savedSelection.select();
    }
}
}
```

```html
<div id="div2">   

   <button class="btn-light"  id="button1" onclick="CopyToClipboard('div1')" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Copy">Copy the text</button>
   <div id="div1" >copy it</div>
   <div id="div3">Other Text</div>
     
</div>

<p>
Other Text for testing restoration.
</p>
```